# Object not set to ref of an obj List Initialization

Tags: c#, object

I am trying to initialize a list in a class but it thows object not set to an instance of an object

Objs

```
    class te1
    {
       public t2 test2 {get; set;}
       public string tst {get; set;}
    }
    class t2
    {
       public List<string> da {get; set;}
    }
```

Calling (this is what throws the error)

```
  var data = new te1();
  data.t2.da = new List<string>();
```

Comment: `t2` is not a static class, you need to initialize it with its default constructor before using `da` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize test2 as well before using **`da`** listIt should be like,

```
var data = new te1();
data.test2  = new t2();
data.test2.da = new List<string>();
```

Comment: well i am a goofball.. thank you!